# Select related - one object from foreign key

Tags: python, django

**models.py:**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    pass

class Pictures(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='pictures')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_file_path, max_length=64,)
```

So, one car can have many pictures. One page I need to write some info about every car and only one picture of that car.

**views.py:**

```
cars = Car.objects.all().select_related('pictures__image').filter(active=1,).order_by('price').reverse()
```

But it does not works. I use this method in `Car`:

```
@property
    def default_picture(self):
        try:
            return self.pictures.all()[:1][0]
        except IndexError:
            return None
```

But it do one more request to db. Its a bad solution.

How to do what I want with min requests to db?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a single query.  But with django's `prefetch_related()` you can reduce number of queries to two:

```
cars = Car.objects.all().prefetch_related('pictures')

@property
def default_picture(self):
    pics = self.pictures.all()
    return pics[0] if pics else None
```

Docs are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related

Comment: and how to use picture`s url in template? ```car.default_picture.url```?

Comment: No. To show ImageField's url in template you have to use `image` field. And don't forget to show `MEDIA_URL` path to uploaded images: `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ car.default_picture.image }}" />`

Comment: thanks! Does I every time has 2 queries? 50 cars - 2 queries?

Comment: Yes, in this case it will be 2 queries every time :-)  But I recommend you to read manual at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related for detailed description of a prefetched cache.